# How to login to a webpage and get its html code with Java, when it uses post method for logging in?

Tags: java, http

I created an application that parses content of secured areas of one webpage after account information input. It used GET method for loging in, so it was quite simple, I just used URL to log in. 
Now it was changed to POST method and I wonder how to log in to that site? The login form uses 2 input tags of type text with names 'login' and 'pass'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using something like [apache commons http](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). You can use [post method](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the request method?

```
HttpURLConnection conn = new HttpURLConnection(url);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(...);
Object content = conn.getContent();
```